# Terraform Code to AWS Lambda Trigger Code

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

How can we give SNS topic arn as trigger to lambda in below Terraform Code?

(My requirement is to trigger the lambda code when SNS topic creation)

```
resource "aws_lambda_invocation" "example" {
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda_function_test.function_name

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      aws_lambda_function.example.environment
    ]))
  }

  input = jsonencode({
    key1 = "value1"
    key2 = "value2"
  })
}
```

Thanks in advance.

PS.

```
InvokePutBucketNotificationLambda:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::CustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - PutBucketNotificationLambda
          - Arn
      AccountId:
        Ref: AWS::AccountId
      Region:
        Ref: AWS::Region
      Configurations:
        - Bucket: cloudtrail-acct-logs
          Prefix: ''
          TopicArn:
            Ref: NewSnsTopic0
    DependsOn:
      - PutBucketNotificationLambdaLogGroup
      - PutBucketNotificationLambdaPolicy
      - NewSnsTopicPolicy0
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what the code currently does? Under what circumstances would your SNS topic be recreated? Why do you not reference the SNS topic anywhere in the code, e.g. within the `trigger`!?

Comment: Hi,
Yes, External monitoring system will put some data to S3 bucket and it will create SNS and SNS will create SQS. So, Lambda should trigger accordingly.

Comment: But what you describe is something entirely different compared to a `aws_lambda_invocation`. A `aws_lambda_invocation` will trigger when you run `terraform apply`, it will not run when anyone puts anything in a bucket. And are you sure you are not confusing an SNS notification with an SNS topic and an SQS message with an SQS queue. They are like an S3 bucket to an object. One is the container, the other is the content. Dynamically creating topics and queues sounds very unlikely to be desirable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
I will check again. I'm trying to convert someone else node.js CFT to terraform with Python.
Thanks again

Comment: I have added the CFT code which has invocation part. When I look in terraform I got first code bit as the invocation code.